# Is there a way to set up the LAN connection to connect via proxy, instead of through the browser?

Tags: proxy, connection, lan

Is there a way to set up the LAN connection to connect via proxy, instead of having to set the browser connection up? If the LAN is set up to go through proxy, then all applications - even non-browser ones, will go through the proxy, and that's what I'm trying to do.

Microsoft Windows Vista

Answer (score 0):

Lisa,

I personally have never seen a way to do this other than the browser route, one way i can suggest though is to set it up on your router. This would force everything out through a proxy.
Not knowing what you want to do makes it harder to answer but this site contains some information provided by people who are trying to use proxies to fool websites into thinking they are based elsewhere to allow them to access web content they would not be allowed outside the UK.

http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=44509

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, I used a program called SocksCap to force various programs that didn't support proxy servers to work through a socks proxy.

A little searching the web found me a similar, newer program called [WideCap](http://widecap.com/), which appears to have a similar function/purpose.

Answer (score -2):

What you're looking for is a system-wide proxy setting.  A quick Google search of "windows system proxy" should help.